# Too many values to unpack: for loop with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a nested dictionary using a for loop to display all the books in a certain language. I want it to display Title, author, Type, and the copies sold. I'm getting the following error on the last line:

```
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The error is thrown on the line containing:

```py
for key,val in dictByLang[askedLanguage]:
```

Here is the dictionary and the rest of the code.

```py
books = {'A Tale of Two Cities': {'auth': 'Charles Dickens', 'Lang': 'English', 'Type': 'Historical Fiction', 'sold': '200000000'}, 'Don Quixote': {'auth': 'Miguel de Cervantes', 'Lang': 'Spanish', 'Type': 'Satire', 'sold': '500000000'}, 'The Lord of the Rings': {'auth': 'J. R. R. Tolkien', 'Lang': 'English', 'Type': 'Fantasy', 'sold': '150000000'}, 'The Alchemist': {'auth': 'Paul Coelho', 'Lang': 'Portuguese', 'Type': 'Fantasy', 'sold': '150000000'}, 'The Little Prince': {'auth': 'Antoine de Saint-Exupery', 'Lang': 'French', 'Type': 'Fantasy', 'sold': '140000000'}}
dictByLang = {}
for key, val in books.items():
    if val["Lang"] not in dictByLang:
       dictByLang[val["Lang"]] = {}
    dictByLang[val["Lang"]].update({key:val})            
askedLanguage = input("What language? ")
if askedLanguage not in dictByLang:
    print("Not a valid language")
else:
    for key,val in dictByLang[askedLanguage]:
        print(key, val['auth'], val['type'],val['sold'])
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You need to iterate over `dictByLang[askedLanguage].items()`, rather than  just `dictByLang[askedLanguage]` (which only iterates over the keys).
2. The `'type'` key in your `for` loop needs to have a capital T.

So, the `for` loop should look like the following:

```py
for key, val in dictByLang[askedLanguage].items():
    print(key, val['auth'], val['Type'], val['sold'])
```